# Contracts: How to Accept Functions of Any Matching Signature?

Tags: racket, datacontract, contract

I'm trying to write this contract: "accept a function that takes at least one argument, and returns a boolean."

The key thing is that I only care that it returns a boolean, and that it accepts one or more arguments -- for instance, it could be a function accepting a single argument, or a function accepting 2 arguments, and either should be accepted.

Here's what I've tried:

**First attempt**:

```
(-> any/c any/c ... boolean?)
```

**Second attempt**:

```
(->* (any/c)
     (any/c ...) ; => syntax error
     boolean?)
```

**Third attempt**:

```
(->* (any/c)
     #:rest (listof any/c)
     boolean?)
```

In each of these cases, it seems the contract is expecting the argument not to just be entailed in the contract specification but to *match* it exactly. That is, for instance, it *must* be a function that accepts arbitrarily many arguments instead of "if it's a function accepting 2 arguments, that's fine because I'm accepting functions that take an arbitrary number of arguments."

How does one write such a contract?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this work?

```
(define/contract (f x)
  (and/c (unconstrained-domain-> boolean?)
         (lambda (p)
           (let loop ([n (procedure-arity p)])
             (match n
               [(? number? n) (>= n 1)]
               [(arity-at-least n) (>= n 1)]
               [(list xs ...) (ormap loop xs)]))))
  #t)
```